# In C#, Is there a way to drag a DataGridView cell's content to another cell?

Tags: c#, datagridview, drag-and-drop

I have `DataGridView dgv`. In one of the cell's of dgv, I have a cell that is shaded gray with a number (the rest of the cells are blank and white). I would like to be able to right and drag that shaded cell to another cell in that column and obtain information from the previous cell's location, value, row #, column # etc as well the new cell's location, value, row/column. Is this possible? This is very similar to a chess board, where the 'piece' is moved from one cell to another by dragging it.

Answer (score 5):

The code below works, though can almost certainly be tidied up a little. It is based on the example from the [DataGridViewFAQ](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CFUQFjAA&url=http://windowsclient.net/Samples/Go%2520To%2520Market/DataGridView/DataGridView%2520FAQ.doc&ei=cl8EUM_-PMKXsgaf24TkBg&usg=AFQjCNFxVe3EWtsJNP7xXxENGfV6dxU0EQ). In that example they drag rows around so I changed things a little to move cell values and to work with the right mouse button.

One thing I didn't get working (though I didn't spend very long on it) was passing the dragged cell using the `DoDragDrop` parameters. The object was coming through null so I just placed it in a form level variable instead.

```
private DataGridViewCell drag_cell;

private Rectangle dragBoxFromMouseDown;

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    dataGridView1.AllowDrop = true;
    dataGridView1.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(dataGridView1_MouseDown);
    dataGridView1.MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(dataGridView1_MouseMove);
    dataGridView1.DragOver += new DragEventHandler(dataGridView1_DragOver);
    dataGridView1.DragDrop += new DragEventHandler(dataGridView1_DragDrop);
}

private void dataGridView1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if ((e.Button & MouseButtons.Right) == MouseButtons.Right)
    {
        // If the mouse moves outside the rectangle, start the drag.
        if (dragBoxFromMouseDown != Rectangle.Empty &&
            !dragBoxFromMouseDown.Contains(e.X, e.Y))
        {

            // Proceed with the drag and drop, passing in the list item.                    
            DragDropEffects dropEffect = dataGridView1.DoDragDrop(
            dataGridView1.Rows[rowIndexFromMouseDown],
            DragDropEffects.Move);
        }
    }
}

private void dataGridView1_DragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move;
}

private void dataGridView1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    // The mouse locations are relative to the screen, so they must be 
    // converted to client coordinates.
    Point clientPoint = dataGridView1.PointToClient(new Point(e.X, e.Y));

    // Get the row index of the item the mouse is below. 
    DataGridView.HitTestInfo hti = dataGridView1.HitTest(clientPoint.X, clientPoint.Y);
    DataGridViewCell targetCell = dataGridView1[hti.ColumnIndex, hti.RowIndex];


    // If the drag operation was a move then remove and insert the row.
    if (e.Effect == DragDropEffects.Move)
    {
        targetCell.Value = drag_cell.Value;
        dataGridView1.Refresh();
    }
}


void dataGridView1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right)
    {
        DataGridView.HitTestInfo hti = dataGridView1.HitTest(e.X, e.Y);
        drag_cell = dataGridView1[hti.ColumnIndex, hti.RowIndex];
        // Proceed with the drag and drop, passing in the list item.                    
        DragDropEffects dropEffect = dataGridView1.DoDragDrop(
        drag_cell,
        DragDropEffects.Move);
    }
}
```